# Numlock on login screen on Ubuntu gnome 16.10

Tags: gnome, login, 16.10, login-screen, numlock

Numlock is not enabled on my ubuntu gnome 16.10 login screen.
It was perfectly working with 16.04.

I tried several tricks but none of them works:
- adding numlockx in /etc/rc.local => no difference
- adding numlockx (with a little script) in /etc/gdm3/Init/Default => No difference
- adding numlockx on in startup apps => no effect.
....

Any idea on how to enable numlock at login on ubuntu gnome 16.10 ?

(after login, numlockx on / off works perfectly).

Comment: I have seen this one. but none of the solutions works (and some are not application to ubuntu gnome)

Comment: seems to work since I uncommented the ligne "WaylandEnable=false" in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf. + various modification I have tried before